# CI/CD: how to exclude complete pipeline for non matching branches

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket

I want to run my pipeline only for `branches =[master, develop, feature/*]` if anyone creates a branch other than the mentioned above then the pipeline shouldn't run.

If there a way to ignore the complete pipeline instead of going to each job and put several conditions?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a job template with your specific rules and use it in your jobs with [extends](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends).

```
.pipeline_rules:
    rules:
        if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^feature\/.*$/'

first_job:
    extends: .pipeline_rules
    script: ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer, it is a workflow that controls the complete pipeline,
I just need to add a single workflow with rules and tada! the work is done.

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
      - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^feature/'
        when: always
```